# Unable to add restricted profile on Xperia Z2 tablet

Tags: sony-xperia, multi-user, restricted-profiles

I would like to add a [restricted profile](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3175031). I'm on an Xperia Z2 **tablet** (so **not on a phone**, where you can't use restricted profiles) running Android 5.0.2 and I'm the "Owner".

When I go to `Settings` > `Users` there is no option `Add user or profile`, only `Add user`. When I tap `Add user` no `Restricted profile` option is shown:

[image]

Also when I tap `OK` no options regarding restricted profiles are offered.

According to this [support article by Sony on multiple users](http://support.sonymobile.com/ca-en/xperiaz2tabletwifi/userguide/Multiple-user-accounts/), it should be possible on the Z2.

I tried adding a PIN screen lock for the Owner account. That did change the information in the alert shown when adding a new user, but that didn't show the restricted profile option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turns out that LTE versions of the Xperia tablets (tablets with a SIM slot) are treated as if they are a phone, so the option is disabled:

https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-Z3-Tablet-Compact/missing-restricred-user-profiles-on-android-5-0-2/m-p/956279#M455

I opened an issue at Google:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=180281